# Implementing Excel Function in POI API

Tags: java, excel, api, apache-poi

How can I implement an unimplemented Excel function in the POI API without recreating the jars to change the FunctionEval class and possibly some other classes?

Can I just create a function and register it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of formula function you're adding

For User Defined Functions, you can register them. See the [User Defined Functions](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) page for details on both writing them and registering them

For regular built in functions which are missing / not implemented, your best bet is to knock up a implementation and submit it as a patch to be included in POI itself :)

For some more details on writing functions, and how it all works, see [this talk](http://people.apache.org/~yegor/apachecon_us2010/Evaluation_Of_Excel_Formulas_In_POI.pptx) that was given at ApacheCon last year.